# How to handle the same elements in the XSLT and combine them

Tags: xml, xslt

Good morning! I wonder if someone can check this template and recommend on how to combine two elements with values into single element. I am not good in XSLT and trying to gain more and more knowledge. Can I combine the same elements? Is that possible in XSLT? Please advise.

Here's an input XML look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Case>
   <NumberCase>
    <Id>855065623159993</Id>
   </NumberCase>
   <Document>
       <ReferenceList>|9486HSDGH|201JKDF|</ReferenceList>
               <ClaimList>|123456823|123456824|</ClaimList>
       </Document>
       <Document>
       <Lastname>GREEN</Lastname>
       <ReferenceList>|01364</ReferenceList>
       <ClaimList>|123456823</ClaimList>
   </Document>
    </Case>
```

My output so far after the XSLT transform

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Case>
     <NumberCase>
           <ImageId>065623159993</ImageId>
           <Lastname>GREEN</Lastname>
           <SIUReferenceList>
               <ReferenceList>|9486HSDGH|201JKDF|</ReferenceList>
               <ReferenceList>|01364</ReferenceList>
           </SIUReferenceList>
           <ClaimNoList>
               <ClaimNoList>|123456823|123456824|</ClaimNoList>
               <ClaimNoList>|123456823</ClaimNoList>
           </ClaimNoList>
         </NumberCase>
      </Case>
```

Here's my XSLT template so far

```
       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
       <msxsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"></msxsl:text>

       <xsl:template match="Case">       
       <xsl:element name="NumberCase">
             <xsl:element name="NumberCase"> 
                  <xsl:element name ="Id">
                  <xsl:value-of select="NumberCase/Id"/>
              </xsl:element>  

              <xsl:element name ="Lastname">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Document/Lastname"/>
                  </xsl:element> 

                  <xsl:element name ="ReferenceList">
                      <xsl:copy-of select="Document/ReferenceList"/>
                  </xsl:element>       

                   <xsl:element name="ClaimList">                        
                 <xsl:copy-of select="Document/ClaimList"/>              
                   </xsl:element>             
              </xsl:element> 
            </xsl:element>   
           </xsl:template>
         </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My desired output is to combine the two the same elements into one something like these:

```
<ReferenceList>|9486HSDGH|201JKDF|01364</ReferenceList>
<ClaimNoList>|123456823|123456824|123456823</ClaimNoList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've added a bit of extra complexity because `|9486HSDGH|201JKDF|` combined with `|01364` is `|9486HSDGH|201JKDF||01364` (i.e. you get double pipes).

Assuming the first element always ends with a pipe and the second element always starts with a pipes, one solution is to use `xsl:for-each` instead of `xsl:copy`.

For example, for `ReferenceList` you could do this:

```
<ReferenceList>
  <xsl:for-each select="Document/ReferenceList">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ReferenceList>
```

Or this...

```
<ReferenceList>
  <xsl:for-each select="Document/ReferenceList">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1 + number(position() > 1))" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</ReferenceList>
```

Or maybe this....

```
<ReferenceList>
  <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="Document/ReferenceList">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</ReferenceList>
```

Comment: Hi @Tim C. thanks for the reply and sorry for the confusion , I meant just one pipe when adding the last value. How do I avoid the double pipes when combining |01364  to make it look like |9486HSDGH|201JKDF|01364?

Comment: the code suggested above works. Thanks so much in your feedback\solution. However, one minor issue is that it combines the result and it shows as  |9486HSDGH|201JKDF01364. The last two values are combined instead of separated by a pipe.

Comment: See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMs. Perhaps the XML you are using is different to what you have shown in your question?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0, by the way?

Comment: we are using version 1.0

Comment: I tried adding the pipe in the  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2) + '|'" /> but the output is |9486HSDGH|201JKDF|01364NaN....Not sure where this "NaN" come from.

Comment: Using the same XML above, except twisting the parent element tag. Like adding the </SIUReferenceList>  and have the <ReferenceList> under it. the desired output I am looking for is the same to combine and output as <ReferenceList>|9486HSDGH|201JKDF|01364</ReferenceList>

Comment: Use `concat` to join strings together, not `+`, because `+` is purely for arithmetic addition in XSLT.

Comment: Tim C did you mean to do something like this? <xsl:value-of select="concat(ReferenceList,  '/', ReferenceList)/>

Comment: Also, the first element always ends without a pipe and the second element always starts with a pipe.

Comment: I resolved the issue. I did  <xsl:for-each select="Document/ReferenceList">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'')"/>
    </xsl:for-each> and getting the result as <ReferenceList>|9486HSDGH|201JKDF|01364</ReferenceList>

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final template that resolved my issue to merge the same two elements into one.

```
   <xsl:template match="Case">       
   <xsl:element name="NumberCase">
         <xsl:element name="NumberCase"> 
              <xsl:element name ="Id">
              <xsl:value-of select="NumberCase/Id"/>
          </xsl:element>  
          <xsl:element name ="Lastname">
              <xsl:value-of select="Document/Lastname"/>
              </xsl:element> 

              <xsl:element name ="ReferenceList">
                  <xsl:for-each select="Document/ReferenceList">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'')"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:element>       
               <xsl:element name="ClaimList">                        
                  <xsl:for-each select="Document/ClaimList"/> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'')"/>
          </xsl:for-each>            
               </xsl:element>             
          </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:element>   
       </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```